# Apache 2 error after performing Update on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu-server, apache2.2

```
root@ubuntu:-$ apachectl restart
```

Gives me this error:

> apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax
>   error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/perl.load: Cannot load
>   /usr/lib/apache2/modu        les/mod_perl.so into server:
>   /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_perl.so: cannot open s
>   hared object file: No such file or directory Action 'restart' failed.
>   The Apache error log may have more information.

IN line 140 of apache2.conf there is this:

*Include mods-enabled/*.load*

*Include mods-enabled/*.conf*

In the file **perl.load** there is only one line:

```
LoadModule perl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_perl.so
```

Kindly assist me on how I can rectify this as it was working properly until apache did and update and it wont restart now.

Comment: `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_perl.so` file exist?

Comment: Now that file, I added it manually and it still didnt work

Comment: Error message is the same?

Comment: Yeah the error is the same